# How do I create a zip file installer containing WordPress plugin files?

Tags: php, wordpress, zip

I have created my first WP plugin. The plugin dir contains several files, "my_plugin.php," a css files, script, readme, etc.

Oddly, I cannot find a thing on the web on "how do I put these files into a zip archive" so that the plugin can be installed via Admin > Plugins "add new."

Windows' "add to zip folder" doesn't work, as the zipped folder is loaded into the media uploads dir on the server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The files should be in the root of the archived file.

Comment: How do I do this? I don't have a directory structure; all files are in the root dir.

Comment: @JPate You don't need a directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
require_once('my_plugin.php');
```

Added the above line to the plugin php file. Working live now. Thanks!